# How to check multiple CSS properties in a jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I have the below script

```
$('#copyright, #credit, #doom a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('font-size') != '15px') {
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }
});
```

It checks all these IDs' CSS properties for font-size 15px; if it's not 15px then the page will be redirect to example.com.

I want to know how can I add **multiple css properties** in that script. I want to include `position:relative;height:auto;background:#000;`.

It may look like this: (this is only example not the working script )

```
  $('#copyright, #credit, #doom a').each(function () {
        if 
           position:relative;height:auto;background:#000

            { do nothing }

else
        {
            document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

For the sake of modularity and clarity you can separate this process into its own function:

```
function valid(element){
    return (element.css('font-size') != '15px' &&
           (element.css('position') != 'relative' && 
           (element.css('height') != 'auto' && 
           (element.css('background') != '#000');
}
```

And then use it in your code:

```
if (valid($(this)){
    document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
}
```

Comment: exactly yes,...but still the script become long..is there any short way, if same work done with less script....means assign the whole property at once like this:            position:relative;height:auto;background:#000. not separate like you used OR condition..

Comment: hi, @NickZuber i agree that good code, however, i need one thing more in the script, is it possible to declare..that #copyright will hold only 4 css property like 1: font-size 2px: position relative 3: height:auto 4: background:#000 if we try to assign 5th property lets suppose we add margin:auto; then it should redirect the page..it should only hold the 4 property in css if adding another then it should redirect the page...

Comment: @IshaqCounciler you would have to include a custom exception for that

Comment: hi, @NickZuber please share the code i dont know what is a custom exception...i just told you, that every ID you see above #copyright, #credit should hold only 4 css property: like 1: font-size 2px: position relative 3: height:auto 4: background:#000, if adding extra another into it, then page should be redirected.

Comment: @IshaqCounciler Sorry I must have been unclear - what I meant by that was you would have to manually write in the code to handle that specific scenario

Comment: How @NickZuber to do that ?...just give you an idea..think about it. for example <style>#copyright {font-size :2px; position relative; height:auto ; background:#000}</style> if like that then ok, if it is like this: <style>#copyright {margin:auto;font-size :2px; position relative; height:auto ; background:#000}</style> then it should be redirected because it added extra "margin:auto" property in css. thanks.